# How to convert a C# Hashtable to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, hashtable

I tried to convert a hashtable to XML like this, but it didn't work:

```
   var jsonArray = new List<Hashtable>();
   XmlNode xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"Row\":" + jsonArray + "}", 
  "BiddingHistory");
```

Comment: tried the above it didn't work, l have a hashtable list that l want to convert to xml , am happy with what ever works

Comment: You don't need to go from json to xml, you can go straight to xml. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml). If you want to nest the result in a `Row` element you will need to [manipulate the xml after serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/creating-xml-trees-linq-to-xml-2). It would also be pretty easy to loop over your list and create nodes as per second link without using `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: try this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202780/convert-hashtable-to-xml-string-and-back-to-hashtable-without-using-net-seriali

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions l ended up converting the hash table into a datatable then from a Data table to xml.

```
  using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            dataTable.WriteXml(sw);
            xml = sw.ToString();
            xml = xml.Replace("DocumentElement", "ArrayOfDataEDI");
        }
```